# generic function for entity framework for code id

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So I would like to know if anyone knows of the "Best practice" with something like this:

if you have let say 20 tables some of which are:
Organization
Department
Office
...

now I got always a Guid in the column `Id` and a "FriendlyCode" in column `Code`

Now when user puts in a Friendly code on the front end I would like to get him the next "available friendly code". The Codes need to be unique

For each table I would like to define a "Mask" for generating id's
for instance if I got departments I would like the key's to be like `A0001, A0002, A0003, ...`
for instance if I got departments I would also like the key's to be like `B0001, B0002, BA0003, ...`

so when the user defines the type of the department he would define the mask of the Code like:

mask1:`A????`

mask2:`B????`

So the Algorithm should only increment the `?` in the mask

And I would also somewhere define what table that will be used for.

I know you can do something like this:

```
private string NewCode<U>(IQueryable<U> table, string mask = "" )
```

but I don't know how to write such an algorithm. I know how to do it with pure sql and execute it but I would like to stay with Entity Framework if possible since all the other parts of the app is Entity Framework based.

Hope this makes sense.

Thank you

Comment: you have two options for this
1. Create a SP and call it in EF
2. Create a function in SQL Server and then use that function for the column, so that on insert, the default value will be autogenerated from the function than you having to generate. This will be faster and safe to use.

Comment: I agree with @saravanan. Doing this in C# code requires you to prevent concurrency collisions. That's much easier in a stored procedure where you can use locks.